# EF Repository Pattern - Update Logic

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

In BLL

```
public void Update(Product product)
{
  if (repository.GetProductById(product.ID) != null )
  {
      repository.Update(product);
  }
else
  {
  // Display errorrs
  }
}
```

In Repository

```
public void UpdateProduct(Product product)

{

 _dbContext.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

_dbContext.SaveChanges();

}



public Product GetProductById(int id)

{

return _dbContext.Products.Find(id);

}
```

When i run the website, It show this errors

"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

I know what happening. When I call GetProductByID() the product entities attached to DbContext. So When I call Update() it will duplicate the Product entity. Because in Update() I attached existed entity in DbContext.

To solve it. I only call the Update(). But I want to check the Product  existence before update/delete it.

By your design experiences, how to pass this problem with a nice manner ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database for a disconnecting entity like this:

```
public Product GetProductById(int id)
{
    return _dbContext.Products.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
}
```

Alternatively you could do a check like this elsewhere in your code:

```
public bool ProductExists(int id)
{
    return _dbContext.Products.Any(o => o.Id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your context to AsNoTracking() this will stop aspmvc tracking the changes to the entity in memory (which is what you want anyway on the web).

```
_dbContext.Products.AsNoTracking().Find(id);
```

I would recommend you read more about this at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application

Yash